# antlr does not parse when token only mentions one other token

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to learn EBNF grammars with ANTLR.  So I thought I would convert the Wikipedia EBNF grammar to ANTLR 4 and play with it.  However I have had a terrible time at it.  I was able to reduce the grammar to the one step that generates the problem.

It seems if I have one token reference solely another token then ANTLR 4 can't parse the input.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar Hello;
program  : statement+ ; 
statement : IDENTIFIER STATEMENTEND /*| LETTERS STATEMENTEND */ ;
LETTERS : [a-z]+ ;
IDENTIFIER : LETTERS ;
SEMICOLON : [;] ; 
STATEMENTEND : SEMICOLON NEWLINE* | NEWLINE+ ; 
fragment NEWLINE : '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';
```

Notice `IDENTIFIER` refers only to `LETTERS`.

If I provide this input:

```
a;
```

Then I get this error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'a' expecting IDENTIFIER
(program a ;\n)
```

However if I uncomment the code and provide the same input I get legit output:

```
(program (statement a ;\n))
```

I do not understand why one works and the other does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token `a` will only be assigned one token type. Since this input text matches both the `LETTERS` and `IDENTIFIER` rules, ANTLR 4 will assign the type according to the first rule appearing in the lexer, which means the input `a` will be a token of type `LETTERS`.

If you only meant for `LETTERS` to be a sub-part of other lexer rules, and not form `LETTERS` tokens themselves, you can declare it as a `fragment` rule.

```
fragment LETTERS : [a-z]+;
IDENTIFIER : LETTERS;
```

In this case, `a` would be assigned the token type `IDENTIFIER` and the original parser rule would work.

Comment: Ahh that makes much more sense.  Do you have a link for the antlr4 documentation that covers this?